# How do I create a download button with a .eml format?

Tags: html, button

I want to add a button to my website, which you click, and it then downloads a .eml file .

How would I do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a .eml file present in your site's files, what you would do is add an href link around the button tags. So, something like this:

```
<a href="file.eml" download>
            <button>Download My EML File</button>
        </a>
```

Just point the href to the eml file in question. This method worked for me with word documents so it should theoretically work here unless eml files work in a fundamentally different way to all other kinds of files.